# Error even after installing android v4 support library in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Even after installing v4 support library from Xamarin Component Store,I get this error.I tried googling for these problems but I always get the same error in Xamarin Studio while developing android app

[image]

Comment: Try grabbing it from NuGet instead.

Comment: Can you give me the link please @Cheesebaron

Comment: Right click on your project and install from Package Manager or Nuget or whatever it is called in Xamarin.Studio.

Comment: I did @Cheesebaron but still it persists.I am not able to figure out.Please help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is [Xamarin Bug 32498](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=32498)

The problem starts when you are normally installing one of **Xamarin.Android.Support.*** nuget packages.

Then IDE (VS2015 for me) hangs and nothing goes well, so you're forced to shutdown the IDE. After re-openning the IDE and forcing a link to the assemblies and when it comes to build the project, it says :

> package android.support.* doesn't exist

## **Here's what happens in the background:**

**First You Must Know That:**

**Xamarin.Android.Support.*** are actually C# bindings of **google support libraries** (THAT ARE WRITTEN IN JAVA), so they are not completely native and they wrappers of google support libraries (for more about Xamarin C# bindings read : [Binding A Java Library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/)).

**Bug Scenario:**

The time the IDE hangs is the time when it starts downloading **Google Support Library** Sources (about 96 MB) from [the internet](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r16.zip) for each of the **Xamarin.Android.Support.*** packages then extracting it to

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin
```

## **Solutions:**

I propose 2 solutions:

1. A friend told me that using a version other than 22.2.1 would solve the problem ( I didn't try it)
2. Manual Extracting of the package (e.g. Xamarin.Android.Support.v4):

   1. Go to `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin`, delete the folder with the desired library name if it exists e.g. `Android.Support.v4`
   2. Create a path with the desired library name `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\{LibraryName}\22.2.1` e.g. `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\22.2.1`
   3. Download Google Support Library Source from [here](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r16.zip) (v16).
   4. Copy it and extract its content into `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\22.2.10\content`
   5. Open the pre-downloaded archive `android_m2repository_r16`, navigate to `m2repository\com\android\support` and go to `libraryname\22.2.1` (e.g. `support-v4\22.2.1`. Search for and open `libraryName-22.2.1.aar` (e.g. `support-v4-22.2.1.aar` (it opens directly with WinRAR) extract the content of the file to `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\{LibraryName}\22.2.10\embedded` e.g. `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\22.2.10\embedded`
   6. Run the package installation nuget command

## **Edit**

you have to keep a copy of android_m2repository_r16.zip inside `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\22.2.10\`

Comment: thanks man, that helped.... alternatively you can jsut wait few minutes with frozen IDE

Comment: this depends on the internet connection

Comment: The hang is desired as Xamarin.Android was trying to download a specific release of Android Support Repository for you, and you should wait. https://blog.lextudio.com/2016/05/android-support-repository-and-xamarin-android/

Comment: @LexLi yes of course. An alternative to waiting with an unreponsive IDE is to do it manually

Comment: great answer if your country is restricted to download these things, and you want to download it manually, however I found another solution, in xamarin folder there's a zips folder which there's a 2kb zip (corrupted) just copy the downloaded m2repository there and rename it to that 2kb corrupted zip and let ide do it's job...

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t have an issue with that component using xamarin version 3.11.586 and v4 support lib version 22.2.0.0. Would you be able to try this?

Comment: I am having Xamarin version 5.9.3 @AlfonChitoSalano

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is too small and I can barely read the code and error messages.  But it appears that you have Java code in Xamarin Studio and it's generating compile errors.  That would be expected since Xamarin Studio only compiles C#, and not Java.  You'll have to take your current Java code and convert it to C#.

Comment: That java code was generated by xamarin studio itself @SharpMobileCode

Comment: It's still not clear exactly what you're trying to do, and what the issue is.  You're showing a screenshot that is hard to read, and have provided very little information what you tried to do, what you expected to happen, and what is actually happening.