# Xamarin Android Support Library v4 (Incomplete)?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, components

I have started studying Android Dev. Using Xamarin via Visual Studio 2015 Pro.
I can't seem to add the Android Support Library v4 under components.
After I got it from the Xamarin Components Store it reads Incomplete. I have tried removing and adding it a many times already.

[image: Xamarin Android Support Library v4 (Incomplete)]

Comment: Have you tried adding it using the Nuget Package Manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `Nuget Package Manager` you can do it this :

```
PM> Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Design
```

See more detail on the [documentation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design/)

For `Android Support Library v4` you do this :

```
PM> Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v4
```

See more information on the [documentation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4/)

Also take a look at this ["BUG"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915969/error-even-after-installing-andrid-v4-support-library-in-xamarin)

Comment: Thank you so much Skizo. I will try this one. I hope this works i will update you regarding this matter THANK YOU!

Comment: Sorry i did not mean that must have pressed it on my phone while replying. Sorry.